# PySide6/PyQt6 movable QGraphicsTextItem malfunction when changing it's angle - spiraling around cursor when QGraphicsTextItem angle is above 60

Tags: python, pyqt, rotation, position, pyside

I want to create a GUI application that is able to put watermark on a photo and save it - I want to be able to move this watermark by pressing, holding and moving around the cursor, I also need to be able to rotate the watermark angle. However, I've noticed that when I set up the rotation to be above 60 there is a bug when trying to drag the label it starts spiraling around the cursor while the radius of the spiral increases depending on how far I drag the label and how big is the setup angle.

Here is the simplified code - try to set up angle above 60 and drag the label across the screen:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QSlider,
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel
)
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class MovableItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPlainText("Stack Overflow")

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start_position = ev.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = ev.pos() - self.start_position
            new_position = self.pos() + delta
            self.setPos(new_position)
            label_parameters = int(self.pos().x()), int(self.pos().y())
            print(label_parameters)

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.graphical_window = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphical_window.setScene(self.scene)

        self.movable_item = MovableItem()
        self.movable_item.setTransformOriginPoint(self.movable_item.boundingRect().center())
        self.scene.addItem(self.movable_item)

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, minimum=0, maximum=359)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.movable_item.setRotation)

        self.label_rotation = QLabel('{}'.format(self.slider.value()), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda value: self.label_rotation.setText('{}'.format(self.slider.value())))


        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.graphical_window)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_rotation)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Widget()
window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.exec()
```

Here is the example outputs from print(label_parameters) when I drag label slightly down by around 100 pixels - y parameter changes and x parameter slightly changes since I can't move cursor perfectly down in straight line

- when the angle is set up to 30 (which works as intended):

```
(3, 2)
(4, 5)
(6, 8)
(6, 13)
(6, 18)
(6, 22)
(7, 26)
(6, 29)
(6, 32)
(6, 35)
(7, 39)
(7, 44)
(6, 47)
(7, 53)
(8, 59)
(8, 65)
(7, 71)
(7, 76)
(6, 79)
(7, 84)
(8, 90)
```

- At angle 75 (dragged item starts malfunctioning here slightly as the distance made by cursor increases):

```
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
(3, 5)
(3, 9)
(1, 13)
(1, 16)
(2, 20)
(3, 24)
(3, 29)
(3, 32)
(4, 36)
(8, 42)
(10, 50)
(9, 61)
(5, 69)
(0, 73)
(-1, 73)
(0, 72)
(4, 73)
(7, 79)
(9, 87)
(10, 97)
(6, 107)
(1, 112)
(2, 114)
(3, 117)
(4, 121)
(6, 127)
(6, 135)
(4, 142)
(1, 147)
(0, 148)
(4, 151)
(15, 160)
(23, 180)
(26, 201)
(21, 223)
(8, 238)
```

- At angle 90 (the positioning malfunction is clearly visible here):

```
(0, -5)
(6, -8)
(14, -5)
(21, 6)
(22, 21)
(17, 36)
(6, 46)
(-9, 45)
(-21, 29)
(-14, 5)
(19, -12)
(69, 4)
(104, 46)
(98, 106)
(63, 160)
(5, 179)
(-61, 140)
(-83, 55)
(-17, -41)
(133, -71)
(299, 34)
(361, 222)
(258, 441)
(-64, 544)
(-386, 656)
(-685, 768)
(-1308, -63)
```

In order to fix the issue, so the label can follow the cursor at any setup angle as intended, I've tried experimenting with position mapping: mapToParent, mapToScene, mapFromGlobal, however with no success. It seems this feature of dragging a rotated item may be impossible with the PyQT6/PySide6 - if not, is there any workaround?

Comment: Why don't you just use what QGraphicsItem provides? Add `self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)` in the `__init__` and remove those mouse event handlers. Also, change to `self.slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda value: self.label_rotation.setText('{}'.format(value)))`, or, even better `self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.label_rotation.setNum)`.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with item transformations, you **must** always consider that event handlers that rely on local positions are *always* mapped to the item.

This means that any transformation will eventually change the result of item positions, and, consequentially, event handlers that are related to that position.

When you apply a rotation to an item, the `event.pos()` you get is already mapped to local coordinates: see [the `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::pos()` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#pos):

> Returns the mouse cursor position in item coordinates

This is not only important, but also consistent: the mouse event handler gets the position of the event based on where the mouse position according to its *real* state: if you click on the top left corner of a rectangle that is rotated by 45°, you will always get a `0, 0` position.

Now: if you only want to move items, the proper way to do so is to correctly use QGraphicsItem features. In this case, the `QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable` flag, which automatically and correctly move items based on the mouse movements, no matter their transforms:

```py
class MovableItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPlainText("Stack Overflow")
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)

    # no further overrides needed
```

Still, there *are* cases for which you have to manage movements based on the mouse. For these situations, you cannot just rely on the event position and then just call `setPos()`, because the event position is in local coordinates, while the item position is in *parent* coordinates (see the documentation about the [Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system), which is based on the basic Cartesian coordinate system).

In those rare cases, the best solution is to always map event coordinates to the scene, and eventually remap "deltas" to the parent (if it exists); then, update the previous "start point" to the new event position, mapped to the scene.

```py
class MovableItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setPlainText("Stack Overflow")

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start_position = self.mapToScene(ev.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            newPos = self.mapToScene(ev.pos())
            if self.parentItem():
                delta = (
                    self.parentItem().mapFromScene(newPos) - 
                    self.parentItem().mapFromScene(self.start_position)
                )
            else:
                delta = newPos - self.start_position
            self.setPos(self.pos() + delta)
            label_parameters = int(self.pos().x()), int(self.pos().y())
            print(label_parameters)
            # IMPORTANT!
            self.start_position = newPos
```

Note that this approach has limitations: notably, it doesn't consider position boundaries that eventually limit the position changes, normally done within `itemChange` overrides.

The simplest solution is the one given at the beginning: just set the `ItemIsMovable` flag on the item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish the item's coordinate system and parent's coordinate system. When calling the `QGraphicsItem.setPos(pos)`, the `pos` should be in parent coordinates. And the `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent.pos()` returns a position in item coordinates. Also, you are accumulating the difference by calculating a new position incorrectly based on the previously calculated position in the `MovableItem.mouseMoveEvent()`.

So, do like this.

```
class MovableItem(QGraphicsTextItem):
    ...
    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.offset = self.pos() - self.mapToParent(ev.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setPos(self.mapToParent(ev.pos()) + self.offset)
```